# memcache telnet flush_all not removing all items

Tags: macos, memcached

I'm new to using memcache so I might be missing something obvious. I use telnet to connect to memcache, then try flush_all and get the message 'OK'. I then run 'stats items' and see a list of items still. When I run 'stats cachedump 16 100' I still see the items listed. I can get where I want if I kill the memcache server and let it restart on it's own (actually trying to debug how to handle errors when memcache fails) but it'd be fastest to just wipe as if it restarted thank use PID to kill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to kill the process.

Memcache does not deallocate memory when you do flush_all. It just sets the expiry time of all the objects in memcache to current time. When you do get for a key it will do return null and the object will be cleared. It uses a lazy approach to flush all objects.

You can read the wiki [here](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#flushall). Go to the end of the page.